# my java doesnt have error, yet not running

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm new to this java language so im still having a hard time figuring things out, though i got no error, but still doesnt run. help me figure this thing out. I posted same program of this though the problem is way back i already figure out.

```
public Connection dbConnection() throws Exception
{
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    String filename =
        "C:/Documents and Settings/gebs/Desktop/Database1.mdb";// fileplace
    String database =
        "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=";// connection driver
    database += filename.trim() + ";DriverID=22;READONLY=true}";
    return DriverManager.getConnection(database, "", "");

    try
    {
        Connection con = dbConnection();

        String lname = this.jTextField1.getText();
        String fname = this.jTextField2.getText();
        String mname = this.jTextField3.getText();
        String address = this.jTextField4.getText();
        String birthday =
            (String) this.jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()
                + this.jTextField5.getText() + this.jTextField6.getText();
        String gender = (String) this.jComboBox2.getSelectedItem();
        String age = this.jTextField7.getText();
        String contactno = this.jTextField8.getText();
        String contactperson = this.jTextField9.getText();
        String department = this.jTextField11.getText();
        String position = this.jTextField12.getText();

        // to insert to database
        String query =
            "INSERT INTO Personal_Category "
                + "(Last_Name,First_Name,Middle_Initial,Address, "
                + "Birthday,Gender,Age,Contact_No,Contact_Person,"
                + "Department,Position) "
                + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,)";

        PreparedStatement pre;
        pre = con.prepareStatement(query);
        pre.setString(1, lname);
        pre.setString(2, fname);
        pre.setString(3, mname);
        pre.setString(4, address);
        pre.setString(5, birthday);
        pre.setString(6, gender);
        pre.setString(7, age);
        pre.setString(8, contactno);
        pre.setString(9, contactperson);
        pre.setString(10, department);
        pre.setString(11, position);
        pre.execute();// execute
        con.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is a little vague. Could you provide more details.

Comment: You might want to use proper variable names. `jTextField11` tells me nothing besides that it's a text field.

Comment: If you're new to Java, why are you working with JDBC?

Comment: Besides the `return` issue, you've set `READONLY=true` in the connection string, and the `INSERT` statement looks like it has a syntax error in the values section (an extra comma at the end).

Comment: If you are serious about wanting us to help then you need to provide the entire program, and also any / all compilation error messages and any / all runtime error messages.  "Doesn't work" is NOT sufficient information.

Comment: Also you wrote this: *"... though i got no error"*.  **That is a false statement**.  The code you posted contains a compilation error.  If you provide invalid evidence, you are just making it harder for us to answer in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is your `return` statement:

```
return DriverManager.getConnection(database, "", "");
```

Nothing after this line can ever be reached because the method terminates (i.e. returns) at this point. So the compiler complains.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this your entire code, I don't see any main method statement in your code. You need to create and object of this class in some main method somewhere.